# In this Jquery script for switching a class on hover, How do I simplify it for repeated instances

Tags: jquery

I will need to replicate this functionality for multiple elements on the page, I can achieve it by repeating the function and changing the class name, but is there a simpler way to combine multiple instances or change the class name? In the style sheet I am animating the title of each image when the link is rolled over.

The Function:

```
 $("a.link1").hover(function() {
  $(".img1, .img1over").toggleClass("img1 img1over");
});
$("a.link2").hover(function() {
  $(".img2, .img2over").toggleClass("img2 img2over");
});
```

the HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="link1">link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="link2">link2</a></li>

</ul>
</div>

            <div class="main">
                <div class="grid img1">
                    <img src="1.jpg" />
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>title</h2>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="grid img2">
                    <img src="1.jpg" />
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>title</h2>
                    </div>
                    </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would need a common class for all your links to simplify your code.

The HTML

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="link" id="link1">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link" id="link2">link2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
                <div class="grid img1">
                    <img src="1.jpg" />
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>title</h2>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="grid img2">
                    <img src="1.jpg" />
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>title</h2>
                    </div>
                 </div>
 </div>
```

The function

```
$('.link').hover(function() {
    var id = $(this)[0].id.substring(4);
    $(".img"+id).toggleClass("img"+id+" img"+id+"over");
});
```

Now you can any number of link using a link class and an id link+number and they will refer to the corresponding img+number.

Answer (score 0):

If you make certain class/id combinations correspond then you can write it once:

```
<a href="#" id="link1" class="hover-link">yep</a>
....
<div id="link1-container">
...
<img src="" class="link-image" />
...
</div> 

$('.hover-link').hover(function(e){
   var $this = $(this),
       baseId = $this.attr('id'),
       $img = $('#'+baseId+'-container .link-image');

       if($img.length > 0) {
          $img.toggleClass('the-class-name');
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably head this way:

```
$("#nav a").hover(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('class').replace('link', '');
    // OR
    // var num = parseInt($(this).attr('class'), 10);

    $(".img" + num).toggleClass("img" + num + "over");
});​
```

I know you are toggling the `img` class as well, but I'd suggest reworking your css instead.
You could also work off the index of the parent `<li/>` instead of clearing out the class name

Answer (score 0):

It is really a strange case, but if you want to stick to your HTML and way of doing this - I would make a simple plugin for that.

http://jsfiddle.net/hkdobrev/8NS89/1/

```
$.fn.toggleHoverClass = function( selector1, selector2 ){
    return this.hover(function(){
        var index = $( this ).parent().index() + 1,
            class1 = selector1 + index,
            class2 = class1 + selector2;
        $( '.' + class1 + ', .' + class2 ).toggleClass(class1 + ' ' + class2);
    });
};

$(function(){
    $( '#nav' ).find( 'a.link' ).toggleHoverClass( 'img', 'over' );
});
```

​If you have any questions, please ask in the comments :)